# How to programatically create a detailed event like z3c.form does?

Tags: python, testing, event-handling, plone, z3c.form

I have a simple [event handler](http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/event-handlers.html) that looks for what has actually been changed (it's registered for a `IObjectModifiedEvent` events), the code looks like:

```python
def on_change_do_something(obj, event):
    modified = False
    # check if the publication has changed
    for change in event.descriptions:
        if change.interface == IPublication:
            modified = True
            break

    if modified:
        # do something
```

So my question is: how can I programmatically generate those descriptions? I'm using plone.app.dexterity everywhere, so z3c.form is doing that automagically when using a form, but I want to test it with a unittest.

Comment: Probably I'm not getting what you need, but if you want to *unit test* the function, why can't you simply call it with mock event parameter? An object that provide the `description` attribute?

Comment: @keul that was the idea, I want to know how to mock a description coming from z3c.form

Comment: Sorry probably I don't get the big picture. It seems that you are probably not doing a unit test (but an integration test?) if you need a real z3c.form.

Comment: @keul most probably I'm not explaining properly, ``event.description`` is a list of interfaces, that z3c.form generates, but I fail to see how to generate them myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

event.description is nominally an IModificationDescription object, which is essentially a list of IAttributes objects: each Attributes object having an interface (e.g. schema) and attributes (e.g. list of field names) modified.

Simplest solution is to create a zope.lifecycleevent.Attributes object for each field changed, and pass as arguments to the event constructor -- example:

```
# imports elided...

changelog = [
    Attributes(IFoo, 'some_fieldname_here'),
    Attributes(IMyBehaviorHere, 'some_behavior_provided_fieldname_here',
    ]
notify(ObjectModifiedEvent(context, *changelog)
```

Comment: Thanks! that made the trick, I was confused because it seemed to me that an approach like that would not work, but the Attributes does some trickery which I was not expecting

Answer (score 0):

I may also misunderstood something, but you may simple fire the event in your code, with the same parameters like z3c.form (Similar to the comment from @keul)?

After a short search in a Plone 4.3.x, I found this in `z3c.form.form`:

```
def applyChanges(self, data):
    content = self.getContent()
    changes = applyChanges(self, content, data)
    # ``changes`` is a dictionary; if empty, there were no changes
    if changes:
        # Construct change-descriptions for the object-modified event
        descriptions = []
        for interface, names in changes.items():
            descriptions.append(
                zope.lifecycleevent.Attributes(interface, *names))
        # Send out a detailed object-modified event
        zope.event.notify(
            zope.lifecycleevent.ObjectModifiedEvent(content, *descriptions))
    return changes
```

You need two testcases, one which does nothing and one which goes thru your code.

`applyChanges` is in the same  module (z3c.form.form) it iterates over the form fields and computes a dict with all changes.

You should set a break point there to inspect how the dict is build.

Afterwards you can do the same in your test case.

This way you can write readable test cases.

```
def test_do_something_in_event(self)

    content = self.get_my_content()
    descriptions = self.get_event_descriptions()

    zope.event.notify(zope.lifecycleevent.ObjectModifiedEvent(content, *descriptions))

    self.assertSomething(...)
```

IMHO mocking whole logic away may be a bad idea for future, if the code changes and probably works completely different, your test will be still fine.